# Subquery cannot execute because of "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition..." Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 tabels:
T1:
`+----+--------------+
| id | timestamp    |
+----+--------------+
| 71 | 19:30:00     |
+----+--------------+`

T2:

`+----+-----------+----------+
| id | timestamp | position |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | 19:30:05  | A        |
|  1 | 19:31:10  | B        |
|  2 | 19:31:35  | C        |
+----+-----------+----------+`

Id's of the tabels are not connected.
For every timestamp of T1, i want to count all rows of T2 where T1.timestamp>T2.timestamp

I tried the query:

```
SELECT id,
(SELECT count(*) from T2 where T1.timestamp>T2.timestamp)
FROM T1
```

I got an error: "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."
Is there any way to achive this?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ANY_VALUE(t1).*, COUNTIF(T1.timestamp > T2.timestamp) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table1` T1
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table2` T2
GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(T1)
```

If to apply to dummy data (similar to those in your question) as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 71 id, TIME '19:30:00' `timestamp` UNION ALL
  SELECT 72, '19:31:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 73, '19:31:30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 74, '19:32:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 75, '19:35:00' 
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, TIME '19:30:05' `timestamp`, 'A' position UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '19:31:10', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '19:31:35', 'C' 
)
SELECT ANY_VALUE(t1).*, COUNTIF(T1.timestamp > T2.timestamp) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table1` T1
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table2` T2
GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(T1)
```

result is

```
Row id  timestamp   cnt  
1   71  19:30:00    0    
2   72  19:31:00    1    
3   73  19:31:30    2    
4   74  19:32:00    3    
5   75  19:35:00    3
```